# Core-Satellite Portfolio Building Strategy

Tags: investing, etf, investment-strategies, portfolio

I recently heard of the [Core Satellite investment strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%26_Satellite) and found it very interesting and smart.

However, I failed to find other comparable portfolio building strategies and subsequently, a comparison between core and satellite to other strategies.

I would appreciate it if someone could mention some comparable investment strategies. A link to an article comparing between approaches would really help!